# Missing Indexes from ADS 9.1 Dictionary

Tags: indexing, advantage-database-server

On two occasions, a client running ADS 9.1, encountered missing indexes in the ADD after files were accidentally accessed through the OS.

The result was an ADD that had missing indexes that needed to be rebuilt by comparing it to a known good backup.

We would like a better understanding of how/why the Dictionary loses the indexes.  Is this an indication of other problems with corrupted data?  Are there best practices to prevent this?  Will upgrading from 9.10.0.35 prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Would you clarify if the dictionary had additional index definitions and the table did not or if the table had additional index definitions and the dictionary did not.  Also, what type of table (I am assuming DBF, but want to clarify)

Comment: All files are ADT.  ADI files were still present when viewing folder using explorer.  When viewing ADD tables using ARC32, some, not all, indexes were missing.